# Copy bower_components to Azure Web App using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

With an Azure Web App that is deployed to via Visual Studio Team Services.

The 'bower install' build step works perfectly, as the next build step executes tests using these files and these tests pass.

After this, I need a method to copy the bower_components folder into the Azure Web App wwwroot folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FTP Deploy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#ftp) to copy files to your Azure Web App folder. Check this link for reference: [Windows Azure Website: Uploading/Downloading files over FTP and collecting Diagnostics logs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploadingdownloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs/).

To use FTP in your build easily, you can install [FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task) extension and then add it in your build definition to copy the files into Azure Web App via FTP.